# Partager mon courriel avec un certain utilisateur — Share my e-mail address with another user

Tags: support, users

Il y a un utilisateur qui semble de s’engouer au français. Il ou elle envoie des questions très faciles, et j’ai vu que les gens ici trouvent ça encombrant, puisque la plupart de ce qu’il demande a déjà été répondue, ou est couverte de quelques autres ensembles de questions et réponses. On lui dit aussi que la toile et des dictionnaires sont des bonnes ressources pour apprendre le français, et devraient être recourues d’avance. Pour rendre des choses plus faciles : Il s’agit de *Simplicity*. (Je ne lui reproche rien parce qu’il pose aussi des questions utiles.)

Toutefois, je comprends que l’apprentissage de quelqu’un ne s’achemine pas s’il faut toujours scruter la toile pour trouver les renseignements souhaités. L’apprentissage va cahin-caha si l’apprenant doit chercher le moindre fait, tandis que qu’quelqu’un qui a un peu de connaissance de la langue française peut l’aider tout de suite.

Moi, je suis prêt à aider l’utilisateur dudit, malgré que mon français soit mauvais. Je pourrais lui donner des petits coups de pouce pour faire s’acheminer son apprentissage. Je veux bien partager mon courriel avec lui, pour que nous puissions parler entre nous sans nuire ce réseau qui doit toujours être net et bien ordonnée.

Alors comment ? Je ne peux pas envoyer une lettre, et bien sûr, on dirait qu’une tentative à donner mon courriel à un autre étudiant en guise de réponse soit hors sujet. En outre, je ne veux pas que mon courriel soit à la portée de tout le monde.  Je pourrais utiliser le clavardage, mais je ne pense pas que la personne y soit suffisamment disponible pour donner mon courriel.

*Bref : Je veux donner mon courriel à un utilisateur mais je ne sais pas comment.*

J’ai relu la mode d’emploi avant d’écrire cette question, mais je me suis aperçu quel n’y pas de règles séparées pour Meta. Si cette question contrevient un dessein de ce site, alors j’aimerais savoir à quel égard.

Comment: Vous pouvez causer chez Cosette, ou vous pouvez créer une salle de *chat* rien que pour vous. N'est-ce pas là la solution ?

Comment: Pouvez-vous m'expliquer comment ca se déroule?

Comment: Related: https://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/538/est-il-possible-souhaitable-denvoyer-un-message-personnel-%c3%a0-un-autre-membre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le plus simple est surement de discuter [chez Cosette](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette) (cela ne requiert que 20 points de réputation).

Si vous voulez discuter un peu plus discrètement, il est aussi possible de créer votre propre salon de discussion ([*Rooms > mine > create a new room*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new)). Noter que toutes les discussions sont publiques (et même indexées par Google, même si elles ont un très mauvais rang d'indexation).

Comment: Le clavardage est depuis quelques jours en panne: Je ne peux pas faire une nouvelle causette, chaque fois que j’essaie de le faire, une image d’un chat devant un ordinateur apparaît sur mon écran. J’espère que cette fonction sera dépannée bientôt.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a [pas de moyen d'échanger des messages privés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) sur Stack Exchange. [C'est délibéré](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/433#433) : Stack Exchange n'est pas et ne veut pas être un site social, et les messages privés poseraient d'énormes problèmes de modération. En effet, qui dit messages privés dit qu'il faut gérer les abus : pour ce qui se fait en public, le public peut modérer (votes, signalements, …), mais ce qui est privé devrait être modéré entièrement par les modérateurs volontaires (non merci) ou par le personnel de Stack Exchange.

Pour simplement discuter en français, vous pouvez le faire dans le [salon de clavardage](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette). Vous ne serez pas les premiers, en fait c'est le contenu principal du salon. Il n'y a pas beaucoup de monde, donc il vaut mieux convenir d'une heure pour ne pas se retrouver tout seul.